# How to know on what interval solution of ODE is valid

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble finding the interval on which the solution of the following ODE is valid.

$$\begin{cases}y'(t)=\dfrac{1}{\cos(t)^2}\\y(9)=\tan(9)
\end{cases}$$

The solution is $y(t)=\tan(t)$.

On which interval is this solution valid? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. The domain of differentiability of $\tan(t)$ where 
$$D(\tan(t))=\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}$$ 
is $$\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\right).$$
Find the maximal interval in such  domain which contains the initial value $t=9$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sadly I still don't understand how to solve it at all

Comment: See my edit. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I tried that but it needs to be written like x<t<x. What are both the x's?

Comment: @Alex.G What did you try?

Comment: I tried -pi/2 <t<pi/2

Comment: No, you should take the interval that contains the number $9$.

Comment: so I replace k by 9 in ⋃∈ℤ(−/2+,/2+)

Comment: No, you should find an integer $k$ such that $-\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi<9<\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$

Comment: Thank you @RobertZ , you were extremely helpful I got it now!

Comment: I definitely will, thanks! @Robertz